# Why do we require coercivity for showing uniqueness of PDEs instead of injectivity?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, coercive

From what I gather, when working with PDEs we can show the uniqueness of a solution to certain PDE's by requiring that a bilinear form is continuous and coercive. The coercivity of the bilinear form implies injectivity. So why don't we require that that instead of being coercive, that the bilinear form is in fact, injective?

Also, coercivity implies injectivity, so surely limiting the bilinear form to being coercive rather than injective, means we miss out on injective bilinear forms that are injective but not coercive? So why limited is this ok...what is wrong with bilinear forms that are injective but not coercive?

Comment: No nontrivial bilinear form is injective, not even in the basic case of forms defined on $\mathbb R$. Consider $q(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro So only the trivial bilinear form is injective, and as coercivity implies injectivity, hence only the trivial bilinear form is coercive. That doesn't make sense as we have no use for the trivial bilinear form! This post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123773/coercivity-vs-boundedness-of-operator - says that coercivity implies injectivity and doesn't say it only applies to trivial operators (i.e. bilinear forms).

Comment: You are confusing injectivity of the quadratic form $Q(f)=\langle f, Lf\rangle$ with injectivity of $L$. The coercivity of Q is a relatively easy to check condition that implies injectivity of $L$. Checking such injectivity directly can be very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the linear equation $Lu=f$ has uniqueness of solutions is obviously equivalent to injectivity of $L$. But how to check such injectivity in practice?

For finite-dimensional equations, one can use linear algebra: determinants, Gaussian elimination, and so on. None of these methods works in the infinite dimensional setting of PDEs. However, it turns out that the coercivity of the quadratic form $Q(f)=\langle Lf, f\rangle$ is a sufficient (not necessary) condition for injectivity. This is good, because coercivity of $Q$ is something that one can often check by integration by parts or other techniques.

Comment: Ok I get it now, thanks! So we can find injective quadratic forms by checking for coercivity. Are 'most' (non-degenerate) functions that are injective coercive? I am wondering about all the injective functions that are not coercive that we are missing out on because we can't check if they are injective..are we missing out on lots of good functions?!

Comment: I am going to be blunt. DO NOT CONFUSE the linear operator $L$ with the quadratic form $Q(f)=\langle Lf, f\rangle$. It is the first that is injective, not the second. Now coming to your question, the answer to that lies in the world of "spectral theory".